# What are the consequences of "band" membership under Canada's Indian Act?

Tags: canada, aboriginal-law

Canada's [*Indian Act*, R.S.C. 1985, c. I-5](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/i-5/FullText.html) recognizes "bands," "members of a band," and "Band Lists."

A band may control its own membership according to membership rules it creates for itself, and with the consent of the majority of the electors of the band.

What are the consequences of membership in an *Indian Act* band?

Answer (score 1):

The consequences of membership in a band include the following:

- this is one path to entitlement to be registered as an Indian in the Indian Register (see s. 6(1)(b)) and all the consequences of that registration;
- eligibility for certificates of possession on the reserve lands of the band (see ss. 20, 24, 81(1)(i)), and when residing on the reserve, being subject to the by-laws created by the band (s. 81(1));
- entitlement to a share of distribution of band money (s. 64);
- eligibility to distribution of up to $3000 of band money for infant children (s. 52.1); and
- entitlement to vote or run for councillor or chief (ss. 74-77).

Note though that the *Indian Act* band structure is only one of several modes of Indigenous governance in Canada. See e.g. the [Nisga'a Nation](https://www.nisgaanation.ca/) and the [many First Nations with self-government agreements in Yukon](https://yukon.ca/en/agreements-first-nations).